# "To go rogue" in German

Tags: translation, phrase, expression

How could this phrase be translated into German?

I can think of

> zu einem wütenden Einzelgänger werden

or similar combinations with different adjectives, but none of them are nearly as concise as the original phrase.

Comment: Is "gegen den Strom schwimmen" an option for you?

Comment: Some suggestions: "unfolgsam sein" or "ungehorsam sein" (disobedience), "abtrünnig werden", "aus der Reihe tanzen", "es auf eigene Faust versuchen"?

Comment: Yeah, "abtrünnig werden" came to mind, too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fully cover the aspect of malice, though.

Comment: There’s no exact and direct translation indeed, @Carlster’s one probably is as close as it gets. _ausrasten, austicken_ or _das Zepter/das Recht/die Dinge/es in die (eigene) Hand nehmen_ may fit sometimes, or some phrase with _Einzelkämpfer, Einzelgänger, Ein-Mann-Armee_ …

Comment: Well, thank you for "ausrasten" - could've thought of that... It covers quite a few situations I wanted to use it in, although it seems only intuitively right - can't find it listed as a translation.

Comment: Context, please. A spy going rogue (outwardly unchanged, but secretly passing information to the enemy) is very different from a footballer going rogue (ignores the coach's tactics and instead tries to score by himself) or a politician going rogue (changes parties, or perhaps starts a new one). There are felicitous German expressions for all of those and more, but they're not going to be the same for all cases.

Comment: A bit in the direction of the mentioned `ausrasten`: `durchdrehen`.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to find a translation which is as concise as the English counterpart. Maybe

> zum rebellischen Einzelgänger werden

*Einzelgänger* kennzeichnet die Wahl, vom Mainstream abzuweichen und *rebellisch* drückt die Art aus. Also eine Person, die kein introvertierter Einzelgänger ist, sondern jemand, der nicht mehr die Befehle von anderen ausführt und eigenständig handelt.

Answer (score 3):

The other suggestions sound strange, I would use ***abtrünnig werden***.

See also [this Leo discussion](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=546497&idForum=2&lang=de&lp=ende).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to translate it without context. I'll try to provide some context to all examples above, maybe some fit for you.

*gegen den Strom schwimmen* you always try to do the opposite of the mainstream

*unfolgsam sein" or "ungehorsam sein" (disobedience), "abtrünnig werden", "aus der Reihe tanzen"* are mostly just used in military context, with the meaning, you don't follow your leader. But there is no anger or something in the meaning, you just dislike your orders an do something else.

*"es auf eigene Faust versuchen"*  there has to be a group with you don't want to follow, so you try on your own

*ausrasten, austicken* I like these examples, they reflect the anger part in "going rogue"

*das Zepter in die (eigene) Hand nehmen* not used in daily German, maybe used in a novel in dark age context

*das Recht in die (eigene) Hand nehmen* sounds like Billy the Kid is killing the Sheriff. You can use this but bear in mind that people will get this Wild West image in their head

*die Dinge in die (eigene) Hand nehmen* I don't like this, it's like do it your self (selber machen), there's no anger and power in this translation

*Einzelkämpfer, Ein-Mann-Armee* mostly used in military situations or in daily business where you try to rise to the top in your company (Einzelkämpfer, not Ein-Mann-Armee)

*Einzelgänger* is someone who doesn't like to be in a group of persons, this doesn't mean he/she doesn't like the persons or their orders, this person just likes to be alone

*zum rebellischen Einzelgänger werden* I really belief that no German would ever use this. Maybe a film critic to describe the plot of Rambo ;)